# How to integrate Flow's type checking into a gulpfile with babelify?

Tags: javascript, gulp, babeljs, flowtype

I'm trying to integrate Facebook's Flow into my project. I can't figure how to integrate the type checking into my gulpfile task.

You can see below my gulpfile without type checking (largely inspired from the recipe on browserify[1]). It just strips the type annotations.

```
gulp.task('build', function () {
  return browserify(sourceFiles, {debug: true})
    .transform(
      "babelify", {
        presets: ["es2015"],
        plugins: [
          "transform-function-bind",
          "transform-flow-strip-types"
        ]
      })
    .bundle()
    .pipe(source("my-lib.js"))
    .pipe(buffer())
    .pipe(sourcemaps.init({loadMaps: true}))
    .pipe(sourcemaps.write())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/'));
});
```

1. https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/recipes/browserify-transforms.md

Comment: This is almost exactly where I'm stuck. I'm sure the answer winds up being obvious, any chance you figured this out?